# ¿Como ejecutar un método u otro según la palabra escrita en EditText?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando realizar algo pero no sé como podría hacerlo. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Tengo un `EditText` y mi intención es que según lo que escribas en el, al hacer clic en mi `Boton` se ejecute un método y otro.

Por ejemplo que las palabras correctas solamente sean: "*Hola*", "*Salut*" y *Hello*", si escribes una de esas tres palabras y se hace clic en el `btn1` se ejecute el primer método.  Pero si se escribe cualquier otra palabra o ninguna se ejecute el segundo método. ¿Es esto posible?

Dejo aquí lo que he podido hacer de código.

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText text1;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // si la palabra es correcta:
                Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
                Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "No es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias,  OK ya veo si! agrego respuesta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declara un array con las palabras, esto para que no tengas que escribir un código extenso si es que necesitas más palabras y escribir muchas comparaciones en una linea (evitar [complejidad ciclomática](http://www.javiergarzas.com/2007/10/complejidad-ciclomtica-o-la-mtrica.html)), además es más optimo:

```
private String[] palabras = {"Hola", "Salut", "Hello"};   
private boolean palabraEncontrada = false;
```

realiza una comparación con el texto dentro del `EditText`:

```
     btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                for(String palabra: palabras){
                   if(palabra.equals(text1.getText().toString())){
                    // si la palabra es correcta:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      palabraEncontrada = true;
                      break; //Si encuentra coincidencia detiene la ejecución del for.
                    }                    
                }

                if(!palabraEncontrada){ //no se encontro coincidencia.
                   // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No es correcto", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } else {
                    palabraEncontrada = false; // reinicia estado de variable.
                 }                        


                }
            });
```

e incluso si usas un Array puedes usar :

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // si la palabra es correcta:
        if(Arrays.asList(palabras).contains(text1.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: Volver palabraEncontrada = false; nuevamente para que no se quede verdadera con un else al final.

Comment: Hola Andres, si lo he agregado para reiniciar la variable, gracias! @Andrespengineer

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys ! Es el método que mejor me ha funcionado para lo que quería hacer, marco como respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 6):

Puedes intentar utilizando un Array con las palabras (opciones) de respuesta, y luego usar Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue) para ver si la palabra que escribio en el EditText esta dentro de las opciones correctas.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
public class Main5Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText text1;
Button btn1;
String[] correctAnswers = {"Hola", "Salut", "Hello"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String answer = text1.getText().toString();

            // si la palabra es correcta:
            if(Arrays.asList(correctAnswers).contains(answer)){
                Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
            }else{
            // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
                Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "No es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Funciona correctamente, +1

Answer (score 4):

Pues sencillo:

```
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if((text1.getText().toString().equals("Hola")) || (text1.getText().toString().equals("Salut")) || (text1.getText().toString().equals("Hello")))
                {
                    // si la palabra es correcta:
                   Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
                    Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "No es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }               

            }
        });
```

Comment: No funciona, escriba lo que escriba siempre se ejecuta el segundo método. Pero gracias por tu respuesta @FederHico !

Comment: Esto debe funcionar también, solo que el método para obtener el texto del EditText es getText().toString() no GetText(); ya se cambio en la respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pides lo puedes realizar sencillamente en una comprobación dentro del click Listener del botón. Bastaría con comprobar que la palabra introducida es una de esas tres que has puesto ( **"Hola", "Salut" y Hello"**) utilizando un `if-else`

P.D.: En el ejemplo he puesto que la comprobación se haga sin importar las mayúsculas y minúsculas con la función `equalsIgnoreCase("hola")` ( si deseas que las palabras sean exactamente las que has puesto en vez de utilizar la función `equalsIgnoreCase("hola")` utilizaríamos la función `equals("Hola")`)

Espero te sirva de ayuda!

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         if((text1.GetText().equalsIgnoreCase("hola")) || (text1.GetText().equalsIgnoreCase("salut")) || (text1.GetText().equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))){
                // si la palabra es correcta:
                metodo1 (); 
         }else{
                // si la palabra no es correcta o no se ha escrito nada:
                metodo2();
         }               
    }
});


public void metodo1(){
     Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "Correcto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //aqui el código que desees ejecutar         
}

public void metodo2(){
     Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this, "No es correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //aqui el código que desees ejecutar         
}
```

Comment: No funciona, escriba lo que escriba siempre se ejecuta el segundo método. Pero gracias por tu respuesta @Joacer !